# Помогите с циклами php

Tags: php, циклы

Есть таблица

```
<tr>
  <td id = '1'></td>
  <td id = '2'></td>
  <td id = '3'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td id = '4'></td>
  <td id = '5'></td>
  <td id = '6'></td>
</tr>
```

Количество столбцов и строк (td и tr) задаются через переменную. ID каждой ячейки должен идти по порядку. Не понимаю, как всё это запихнуть в цикл, что бы задать кол-во столбцов и строк, и таблица сама сгенерировалась

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
$td = 5;
$tr = 5;
$n = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $tr; $i++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($a = 1; $a <= $td; $a++) {
        echo '<td id="' . $n . '"></td>';
        $n++;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Строить таблицу циклом можно например так:

```
              <table>
                    <?php foreach ($items as $item):?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo date("d.m.Y", strtotime($item['date']));?>
                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <a href="/item/item.php?item_id=<?php echo $item['id']?>">
                            <img src="/images/<?php echo$item['image'];?>" class="small-image">
                            </a>

                        </td>

                        <td>

                            <a href="/item/item.php?item_id=<?php echo $item['id']?>">
                            <?php echo mb_strimwidth($item['name'], 0, 30, "...");?>
                            </a>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo number_format($item['price'],0,"."," ");?> руб.
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $item['categoryname'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img src="../images/eye.png" title="Просмотров объявления"> <?php echo $item['views'];?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </table>
```

На выходе что-то такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]